# LD_LIBRARY_PATH not recognized in Pycharm (linux)

Tags: pycharm, environment-variables

I'm trying to run a Geant4 (particle simulation engine) executable called "Cyclotron" from a python script within Pycharm. The file runs perfectly fine when I execute it from the command line, i.e. `./Cyclotron`.

When I try to execute the same bash commands with the `subprocess.check_call()` method, I get the following error message :

```
./Cyclotron: error while loading shared libraries: libG4zlib.so: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicolas/Geant4/geant4.10.04.p01/main_stuff/cyclotron- 
geant4/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(command.split())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./Cyclotron']' returned non- 
zero exit status 127.`
```

which seems to be caused by the fact that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is not recognized inside Pycharm. For example, running

```
import os
print(os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))
```

returns `None`. I've seen people recommending going under `Run->Edit Configurations` and add the variable under Environment variables (I've tried for both my script and Python under Defaults) and still no luck.

On the command line, typing
`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns `/home/nicolas/Root/build/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/nicolas/Geant4/install/lib`.

Here is my python code:

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir("build")

bash_commands = [
    "cmake ..",
    "make -j4",
    "./Cyclotron"
]

for command in bash_commands:
    subprocess.check_call(command.split())
```

and the output:

```
/home/nicolas/PycharmProjects/Main/venv/bin/python 
/home/nicolas/Geant4/geant4.10.04.p01/main_stuff/cyclotron-geant4/main.py
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
/home/nicolas/Geant4/geant4.10.04.p01/main_stuff/cyclotron-geant4/build
[100%] Built target Cyclotron
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./Cyclotron: error while loading shared libraries: libG4zlib.so: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicolas/Geant4/geant4.10.04.p01/main_stuff/cyclotron- 
geant4/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(command.split())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./Cyclotron']' returned non-zero 
exit status 127.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, Pycharm 2018 with a Python 3.6 interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I tried again the next day and Pycharm is able to see the variable now. The only thing I tried differently was to tick the Share box on the top right corner under `Run->Edit Configurations` for my specific python script. Even if I untick it afterwards, the variable is still recognized. The script lightened up when I applied the changes like if it changed from some state to another, but I have not clue of what I modified.

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem with Pycharm-2018.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is the solution:

Run -> Edit Configurations -> Environment -> `Add LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYM0R.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zedux.png)

And The Amazing Happens.